# Not getting any response code from zomato using java

Tags: java, httprequest

I'm trying to call a link that is a resturant on **zomato**.

In **Google Chrome**, it is giving me proper response but when I'm making a call to it using java, It's not giving me any response.

---

Here is the my code:

```
    String urlStr = "https://www.zomato.com/ncr/bercos-sector-12-noida";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        System.out.println("Before getting response code");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("After getting response code");
        System.out.println(responseCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

I'm stuck at **Before getting response code** for some time and then after it throws **SocketTimeoutException** saying **Read Timed out**.

If I'm missing anything please let me know how to make this work. 
Thank you.

Note: My internet is working fine. I tried google's url and it is working.

Comment: why not `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");`?

Comment: Because I just wanted to check if the link is working. I didn't want any overhead of getting the message body back.

Comment: And? Did you try `GET` ?

Comment: Yes. I did. Did not work.

Comment: It seems, guys from **zomato** somehow check if request was send from browser or not. I Tried to add the same headers as browser send, but it doesn't help((

Comment: @IvanKovbas Yes, I tried that too but didn't work.